# LyX fancy header \thispagestyle{fancy}

Tags: header-footer, lyx, preamble

I am using LyX and would like (all) my document pages to have a fancy header style that I defined. However, including

```
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

or

```
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{fancy}}
```

doesn't work! The only way I got it to work is using the ERT command

```
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

at the beginning of the document. Does anyone know how to get over it without using an ERT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\thispagestyle` only pertains to the page that you're calling it on. To make *all* the pages have the `fancy` style, you need to use `\pagestyle{fancy}`. In LyX, it is possible to set this via `Document`->`Settings...` and choosing the "Page Layout" tab with the "Heading style" as `fancy`:

[image]

Note that the standard document classes that contains `\chapter` ([`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) or [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls)) will still use `\thispagestyle{plain}` for the first page of every `\chapter` (this includes title pages, as well as ToC-related first-pages as well, since the latter is issued using `\chapter*`). To avoid this, you have to issue an explicit `\thispagestyle{fancy}` in an ERT *after* the chapter title.

Comment: Thanks. I just figured that my problem arises because of having a title (a simple title, not a title page.) So my only option is to use an ERT?

Comment: @Elec: No, you could add content in your preamble as well. For example, `\makeatletter\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy\makeatother` would overwrite the `plain` page style with that of `fancy`, making any call to `\..pagestyle{plain}` be equivalent to `\..pagestyle{fancy}`. However, such generalizations should be considered carefully, since it may result in headers displaying on pages where headers might look weird (like the first page of a chapter).

Comment: I see. Thanks. It seems like a big bug though, that fancy style cannot be implemented after a title (with usual LyX options)...

Comment: Does this work with IEEE Transactions Document class?

Comment: @zygimantus: Yes... until proven otherwise. However, don't fiddle around with journal-specific document class layouts if you plan on submitting it.